# How Can I integrate ble with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to integrate with ble with react native.(Beacon)
I tried these librarys
"react-native-ble-manager"
"react-native-ble-plx"
and many react-native-beacons librarys.
None of them work.

Do you know how i can integrate ble with react-native.
Should i write code native ?

Comment: Could you explain further what you tried exactly and why the libraries did not work for you?

Comment: I am trying to connect with a Beacon(iTag) device but no library is helping me to connect with this device. I want to data read wtih this device. When i try to libraries no one display the my device. And many libraries too old. (Last update like 5 years ago)  @MichaelKotzjan

Comment: Just to clarify, you are able to use the example apps provided with say react-native-ble-plx but can't connect to the device? Have you tried using an existing BLE scanner like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to connect to your device?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am solved problem from react-native-ble-manager library thank you for your returns